# Does ot-br-posix only support RCP?

Tags: openthread

Google has changed the Default Mode of Border Router to use RCP since last year, so is it correct that ot-br-posix provided by Openthread only supports RCP?

Answer (score 0):

The support of `wpantund` in OpenThread's `ot-br-posix` was dropped with: https://github.com/openthread/ot-br-posix/pull/403. All later `ot-br-posix` commits rely on the RCP model.